# How to dynamically select django model fields in views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am using the DRF and I am trying to dynamically select fields from a django model object so that I can compare them to incoming data. I know how to do this manually

```
def put(self, request):
    businessPage = BusinessPage.objects.get(id=request.data['id'])
    if businessPage.name != request.data['name']:
        businessPage.name = request.data['name']
    if businessPage.address != request.data['address']:
        businessPage.address = request.data['address']        
    businessPage.save()
    res = {
        'status': 'Success'
    }
    return Response(res)
```

While this works it feels very messy and repetitive so I started looking for a way to dynamically check if the object field matched the incoming data.

```
def put(self, request):
    businessPage = BusinessPage.objects.get(id=request.data['id'])
    for obj in request.data:
        if businessPage[obj] != request.data[obj]:
            businessPage[obj] = request.data[obj]
            
    businessPage.save()
    res = {
        'status': 'Success'
    }
    return Response(res)
```

I haven't been able to figure out the correct syntax to get the correct field from `businessPage`. Is this possible? Is there a better way to accomplish this task? Any help here would be much appriciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this:

```
bp_id = request.data.pop("id")
BusinessPage.objects.filter(id=bp_id).update(**request.data)
```

Comment: This worked for what I am trying to accomplish. I did have to add a spread operator to get it to work. `BusinessPage.objects.filter(id=request.data['id']).update(**request.data)`